# Webpack 2 ExtractTextPlugin CSS sourcemaps overwriting babel 6 JS sourcemaps

Tags: webpack, source-maps, uglifyjs, webpack-2, extract-text-plugin

**EDIT:** found a solution shortly after posting this question. See [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42460172/1088373) below.

---

I have a webpack 2 based project that uses [ExtractTextPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to pull out SCSS/CSS into a separate file.

Additionally, I have two entry points defined in webpack (`vendor` and `app`), which build out to my JS bundles.

For some reason, ExtractTextPlugin seems to break the sourcemap generated for the app bundle, `app.js.map`. If I look at the sourcemap, it points to random lines in the extracted CSS file, instead of the JS.

Looking inside the sourcemap file itself, I only see CSS and SCSS files listed under "sources" (shortene sample below):

```
{"version":3,"sources":["webpack:///webpack:///~/icon-font/package/styles/ficon.css","webpack:///webpack:///~/styles/package/styles/_imports.scss","webpack:///webpack:///~/styles/package/styles/includes/_variables.scss","webpack:///webpack:///~/styles/package/styles/includes/_mixins-utilities.scss", .....
```

**however**, if I comment out the `ExtractTextPlugin` in the webpack config, I get JS files listed in sources:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["webpack:///app-552b3935c142f5001484.js","webpack:///./src/lib/Globals.js","webpack:///./src/actions/AdActions.js", ....
```

So not really sure what is going on here... It seems like something about `ExtractTextPlugin` is breaking or overwriting the sourcemap for the app bundle?

Here is how I have all relevant plugins defined in my webpack config:

```
{
  entry: {
    vendors: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-redux',
    ],
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, './../src/client.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './../dist/assets/'),
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js.map',
  },
  cache: false,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: [
            'css?sourceMap',
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass?sourceMap'
          ],
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [path.join(__dirname, '../src')],
        exclude: [NODE_MODULES_DIR],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: false,
      postcss: () => ([autoprefixer]),
      eslint: {
        emitWarning: true,
      },
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendors',
      minChunks: Infinity,
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        drop_console: true,
        collapse_vars: true,
        reduce_vars: true,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        ascii_only: true,
      },
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '_all.[chunkhash].css', allChunks: true }),
  ],
}
```

Any ideas what may be causing this? Could it be some sort of conflict with UglifyJS and the ExtractTextPlugin? a config issue on my part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution shortly after posting this question! Just wanted to answer it incase anyone else encounters this same issue.

I managed to find [this helpful github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/119). The issue lies with the `sourceMapFileName` set in webpack output. Mine was:

```
sourceMapFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js.map',
```

which, coincidentally, would match both the CSS from extractTextPlugin as well as the app bundle. So one was overwriting the other.

Changing that line to:

```
sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
```

allows a unique CSS map and JS map to be generated!

Hope this helps someone. :)

Comment: Finally! You saved me another hour of digging.

Comment: Glad it helped someone else, @Kędrzu! Would be happy to contribute this to the webpack docs.